# ubuntu update packages

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu Lucid installed, need to update packages, when I ran

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

I can see list of packages need to be updated, when I ran '

```
sudo apt-get upgrade  or sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

it said:

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

? how can I update that list of packages? I don't  have a GUI interface only command line interface...

Comment: Do those packages happen to be kernels and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu Lucid user here. When I run `sudo apt-get update` I don't get a list of packages that need updating, I just get the list of the repositories being checked. For example:

```
Get:1 http://packages.medibuntu.org lucid Release.gpg [197B]
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com lucid Release.gpg
Get:2 http://packages.medibuntu.org lucid Release [6854B]
(...)
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade` gives me the list of packages that can be updated, if there are any. If you apt-get says there aren't any updated packages, I guess you can trust it, unless there's some problems with your `sources.list`... But then apt-get update should tell you about them.

By the way, lately I've been using aptitude instead of apt-get: I find it better at managing problems, got me out of a tight corner once or twice... I just do:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, "aptitude update" will tell you how many updates are available before you run the upgrade command.